# Azure ARM - mount StorageAccount FileShare to a linux VM

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

I prepared an ARM template, template creates listed azure resources: linux VM deployment, Storage deployment, file share in this Storage Account.

ARM works fine, but I would like to add one thing, mounting file share to a linux VM (using script from file share blade, script proposed by Microsoft).

I would like to use Custom Script Extension, and then use "commandToExecute" option to paste inline linux script (this one for file share mounting).

My question is: how to retrieve password to file share and then pass it as a parameter to the inline script. Is it possible? Is it possible to paste file share mounting script as an inline script in ARM template? maybe there is any other way to complete my task? I know that I can store script in a storage account and in ARM template put "blob SAS URL" in the Custom Extension ARM area, but still is a question how to retrieve the password to File Shares, below is the script for File share mount.

```sh
    sudo mkdir /mnt/wsustorageaccount

    if [ ! -d "/etc/smbcredentials" ]; then
    sudo mkdir /etc/smbcredentials
    fi

    if [ ! -f "/etc/smbcredentials/StorageAccountName.cred" ]; then
        sudo bash -c 'echo "username=xxxxx" >> /etc/smbcredentials/StorageAccountName.cred'
        sudo bash -c 'echo "password=xxxxxxx" >> /etc/smbcredentials/StorageAccountName.cred'
    fi
    sudo chmod 600 /etc/smbcredentials/StorageAccountName.cred
    
    sudo bash -c 'echo "//StorageAccount.file.core.windows.net/test /mnt/StorageAccount cifs nofail,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/StorageAccountName.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino" >> /etc/fstab'
    sudo mount -t cifs //StorageAccountName.file.core.windows.net/test /mnt/StorageAccountName -o vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/StorageAccountName.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/demos/arm-template-retrieve-azure-storage-access-keys) quickstart example:

```
listKeys(variables('storageAccountId'), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, it helped me, but question, if its possible to paste this mentioned in my post script into ARM template. Is "commandToexecute" field is a correct field to do it?

Comment: depends on how your script works, either command to execute or protected properties

Comment: I have put this line in my variables section `"accessKey": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountId'), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value]"`, and I am receiving an errer --> `Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'accessKey' is not valid: The template 
function 'listKeys' is not expected at this location.`

Comment: you cannot use listkeys in variables, in resource declaration or outputs only (at the time of writing)

Comment: Sorry, but this is still not clear for me, haw can I use `"accessKey": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountId'), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value]"` in my storage account resources section to retrieve storage account key, there is no place/property like: parameters or something similar, I am checking on MS --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2019-04-01/storageaccounts, I want to use storage account key as a param in `"commandToExecute":`

Comment: just use it there, you cannot use it in variables

Comment: Updated my ARM, it created: VM, storage account, fileshare, but still is a problem with the extension. After deployment I am receiving an error: "The handler for VM extension type 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' has reported terminal failure for VM extension 
'LXrepoConfiguration' with error message: '[ExtensionOperationError] Non-zero exit code: 127, /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.10.5/install.cmd
[stdout]
[stderr]
/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension-1.10.5/install.cmd: line 1: binCustomScriptHandler.exe: command not found"

Comment: eh, are you using a windows extension against a linux host?

Comment: Hi, I missed that, corrected ARM and it worked, thanks a lot!!